# How do I incremental search in Atom Editor?

Tags: atom-editor

How can I do an incremental search (similar to Sublime Text's Cmd-F or Cmd-I) in GitHub's Atom Editor?

Answer (score 7):

[find-and-replace](https://atom.io/packages/find-and-replace) is one of the core Atom packages. You can enable incremental search by updating the settings for this package.  Check the option *"Scroll To Result On Live-Search"* and optionally change the *Live Search Minimum Characters* (defaults to 3).

Answer (score 2):

There's an *incremental search* package available now: https://atom.io/packages/incremental-search

It seems to be modeled after incremental search in Emacs.

Comment: Why do you think that? The ownership of the package has been transferred to https://github.com/gangstead in May 2015. There's a note "Update I (@gangstead) have taken ownership of the package. Bear with me as it gets updated and republished" on the Atom package page. The new GitHub repo for this project is https://github.com/gangstead/atom-incremental-search, the last commit was on June 18th, 2015.